# Getting Top/Left of a Text Component

Tags: react-native, tooltip, react-native-cli

I am looking to find the top/left position of each `Text` component. This will sound a bit odd but I tried this and it was giving me `left` & `top` keys for each `Text` component. I was testing it on a Snack.

A few hours later, I try this again & now the `top` & `left` are missing from this. Checked the documentation as well. They don't mention `top` & `left` for `onLayout` callback.

Actually I need to show a tooltip & need to position it. Any pointers, please

**Edit**
Not looking for a Modal based implementation for my usecase

```js
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
 {textArr.map((text, idx) => {
   return (
    <Text
      onLayout={event => {
        // this was giving me x,y,width,height,top,left values
        console.log(event.nativeLayout.layout);
      }}
    >
      {text}
    </Text>
   );
 })}
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Super simple and simplified `Tooltip` implementation with `TouchableOpacity` and `Modal`. Uses pressed location for placement.

```
const Tooltip = ({children, text}) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [location, setLocation] = useState([0, 0])

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={(e) => {
        setLocation([e.nativeEvent.pageX, e.nativeEvent.pageY])
        setShow(!show)
      }}>
      <Modal visible={show} transparent={true} onRequestClose={() => {setShow(false)}}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'lightgray', width: 160, padding: 8, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', left: location[0], top: location[1]}}>
          <Text>{text}</Text>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      {children}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

...

<Tooltip text="Tooltip text">
  <Text>
    Show tooltip for this text
  </Text> 
</Tooltip>
```

Comment: For my usecase, I am not looking for a Modal based solution. thanks for your time, btw